# How to get other people in the unity project in plastic SCM

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

I have a repository in my plastic SCM for my unity game, but I don't know how to get other people in the unity project. I have no idea how to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [PlasticSCM cloud dashboard](https://www.plasticscm.com/dashboard/cloud)
2. Go to "Configure" below your organization and head to "Users and Groups"
   [image: Configure button on plastic dashboard]
3. Click "Add new user" button
   [image: Plastic user management board]
4. Write the email you want to give access to and save
   [image: Add user form]

If your cloud is linked with Unity organization you can just add a user to the organization and it will automatically sync permissions and give access to the Plastic Cloud. [Follow this steps if your cloud is linked with Unity organization](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000532543-How-do-I-invite-a-new-member-to-my-Organization-)

Security notice: If you have multiple projects or multiple people and want to give specific access/permissions I advice you to [read more about permissions in PlasticSCM here](https://www.plasticscm.com/features/security)